# modal appearing when option from select dropdown has been selected

Tags: javascript, html

WEll,

I'm trying to make to appear a modal window if one of the options in a select dropdown is selected. It did work if instead of using the option from the select I use a simple button, but I need it from the select.

The screen change it's opacity though, so I guess I'm doing something.... but wrong. Obviously I have the link and scripts from bootstrap that I need, open and close doc and html too.

Any suggestions?

Thank youuu

```
html
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <select id="selectAction" data-style="btn-info" onchange="newGraph(this)">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option:</option>
        <option value="create">Create a new graph</option>
        <option value="recall">Recall a saved graph</option>
      </select>

      <!--Pop up window-->

      <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUp1">   //it works if I put this in a <button> instead a div, but then, I have to click to button to make the modal to work so it in not what I want.
<div class="modal hide fade" id="popUp1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="popUp1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4>Creating a new graph:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Here some text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div> 


script
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function newGraph(element) {
  if($(element).val() === 'create') {
     $('.toolsHeader').show();
     $('#popUp1').modal();
      $('#selectAction').hide();
  }
   else{ 
    return false;
  }};
```

Comment: You need to put everything into `$(function(){})` and get rid of inline `onchange` thing when using jquery. That's all you need to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this: `onchange="newGraph(this)"` from the HTML.

Add this:

```
$('#selectAction').change(function() {
    newGraph($(this));
});
```

to the JS.

Comment: Good answers should provide an explanation, not just "copy-paste" to make it work

Comment: And also, you could see that `function newGraph(element)` expects `element` to be an instance of `DOMElement` or a selector, not a string, which `$(this).val()` returns.

Comment: @bad_boy, that's for noticing the $(this).val() issue. I fixed that. I would however argue that the best explanation to a problem is self-documenting code. Exactly zero people should have an issue understanding what this code does.